# NoSuchElementException encountered with Databricks version 11.3 and above

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks with pyspark to do some ETL on my dataframe. I was using a compute cluster with DataBricks Runtime version 10.4 and everything used to run perfectly fine. But when I use a cluster with Databricks Runtime version 11.3 or above I come accross a very strange exception.

I have the following snippet of code in notebook that unions two dataframes by name:

```
dfResult = dfA.unionByName(dfB, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

`dfA` is formualted by dropping some columns

```
dfA = (
    dfWithErrId.drop(F.col("OLD.SOME_COLUMN"))
    .drop(F.col("OLD.ERR_ID_COLUMN"))
    .drop("TMP_ERR_ID_COLUMN")
)
```

`dfB` is formualted by filtering another dataframe using `where` on a predefined condition:

```
dfB = dfC.where(f"!({nullSafeErrorCondition})")
```

The code executes wihout problem but when I try to display the `dfResult` as `display(dfResult)` I get the following exception from `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOME_COLUMN#28800`

upon expanding this exception I find that the exception is originated by a `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling t.addCustomDisplayData`.

I would really appreciate if someone can provide an insight on why would such an exception get triggered and how can I reproduce it so that it can be explained that executing so and so would result to triggering this exception.

Thank you in advance!

The full stack of the exception is given below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1645638012697264> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 display(dfResult)

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/display.py in display(self, input, *args, **kwargs)
     81                     raise Exception('Triggers can only be set for streaming queries.')
     82 
---> 83                 self.add_custom_display_data("table", input._jdf)
     84 
     85         elif isinstance(input, list):

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/display.py in add_custom_display_data(self, data_type, data)
     34     def add_custom_display_data(self, data_type, data):
     35         custom_display_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
---> 36         return_code = self.entry_point.addCustomDisplayData(custom_display_key, data_type, data)
     37         ip_display({
     38             "application/vnd.databricks.v1+display": custom_display_key,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    194     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    195         try:
--> 196             return f(*a, **kw)
    197         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    198             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling t.addCustomDisplayData.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOME_COLUMN#28800
            at scala.collection.MapLike.default(MapLike.scala:236)
            at scala.collection.MapLike.default$(MapLike.scala:235)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeMap.default(AttributeMap.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.MapLike.apply(MapLike.scala:144)
            at scala.collection.MapLike.apply$(MapLike.scala:143)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeMap.apply(AttributeMap.scala:55)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$rewriteConstraints$1$1.applyOrElse(basicLogicalOperators.scala:513)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$rewriteConstraints$1$1.applyOrElse(basicLogicalOperators.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:99)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1174)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1173)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:652)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1201)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1200)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:779)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:456)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union.$anonfun$rewriteConstraints$1(basicLogicalOperators.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExpressionSet.$anonfun$map$1(ExpressionSet.scala:119)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExpressionSet.$anonfun$map$1$adapted(ExpressionSet.scala:119)
            at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
            at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExpressionSet.map(ExpressionSet.scala:119)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union.rewriteConstraints(basicLogicalOperators.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union.$anonfun$validConstraints$3(basicLogicalOperators.scala:540)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union.validConstraints$lzycompute(basicLogicalOperators.scala:540)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Union.validConstraints(basicLogicalOperators.scala:536)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.QueryPlanConstraints.constraints(QueryPlanConstraints.scala:34)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.QueryPlanConstraints.constraints$(QueryPlanConstraints.scala:32)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.constraints$lzycompute(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.constraints(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join.validConstraints$lzycompute(basicLogicalOperators.scala:628)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join.validConstraints(basicLogicalOperators.scala:611)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.QueryPlanConstraints.constraints(QueryPlanConstraints.scala:34)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.QueryPlanConstraints.constraints$(QueryPlanConstraints.scala:32)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.constraints$lzycompute(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.constraints(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$32.$anonfun$applyOrElse$38(Optimizer.scala:1824)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$32.$anonfun$applyOrElse$38$adapted(Optimizer.scala:1823)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$partition$1(TraversableLike.scala:450)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.partition(TraversableLike.scala:450)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.partition$(TraversableLike.scala:448)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.partition(Traversable.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$32.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1823)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$32.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1799)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:99)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1174)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1173)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:254)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1174)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1173)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:254)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
            at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
            at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
            at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
            at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:626)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1174)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1173)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:254)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1174)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1173)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.GlobalLimit.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:1664)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:517)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:478)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1799)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1797)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$3(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
            at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
            at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
            at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
            at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
            at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:184)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:153)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:184)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:278)
            at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:319)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$3(QueryExecution.scala:349)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:777)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:349)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:346)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:274)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:270)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertOptimized(QueryExecution.scala:288)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:307)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:304)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:394)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:463)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainStringLocal(QueryExecution.scala:425)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:392)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:188)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:142)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:342)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4288)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3414)
            at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:267)
            at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:101)
            at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:720)
            at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:1332)
            at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal$JupyterEntryPoint.addCustomDisplayData(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:489)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor528.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
            at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I don't have an answer for you right now, but my suggestion is to post this on Databricks community as well if you haven't already. Databricks SA's and engineers actually monitor those threads regularly, and might be able to get you an answer. They made a big push maybe 9 months ago to start expanding that forum. I'll try to check their slack channel on Monday for any similar reports, and see if field eng has an answer.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! Appreciate it!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).